# Does anyone have a good example of a ProcessFunction that sums or aggregates data at some frequency

Tags: apache-flink

I am looking mimic the behaviour of a window().reduce() operation but without a key at the task manager level.  Sort of like a .windowAll().reduce() does for a stream, but I am looking to get individual results from each task manager.

I tried searching for "flink processFunction examples" but not finding anything useful to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ProcessFunction examples, I suggest the examples in the [Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/process_function.html#example) and in the [Flink training materials](http://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/longRides.html).

Another approach would be to use windows with a random key selector. That's not as easy as it sounds: you can't just select by a random number, as the value of the key must be deterministic for each stream element. So you could add a field that you set to a random value, and then keyBy that field. Compared to the ProcessFunction approach this will force a shuffle, but be simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the training materials.  I came up with an alternate approach that meets my needs after looking these over.